# Want to make dictionary key inputted by user in a python function argument

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key

```
def build_profile(f_name,l_name,**qualification):
    profile={}
    profile['first']=f_name
    profile['last']=l_name
    for k,v in qualification.items():
        profile[k]=v
    return profile
pl=[]
while True:
    pl.append(build_profile(input("Enter first name: "),\
    input("Enter last name:"),graduation=input("Enter Subject:"),\
    masters=input("Enter Subject:")))
    if input("Want to finish?(Y/N) ").upper()=="Y":
        break
print(pl)
```

The given function accepts user input values for 'graduation' and 'masters' key but I was thinking that for different users level of education might be different some might be PHD and some might not have even completed High school. I tried to convert the key values for the dictionary 'qualification' to be input by user but whenever i convert

```
graduation=input("Enter Subject:")
```

to

```
input("Enter value:")=input("Enter Subject:")
```

I get an error "Keyword can't be an expression". On searching internet i knew about split() function in python can accomplish it but I was not able to make it work in my code.

#SOLVED
Based on answers I modified my code as below and now its working as i desired:

```
def build_profile(f_name,l_name,qualification):
    profile={}
    profile['first']=f_name
    profile['last']=l_name
    for k,v in qualification.items():
        profile[k]=v
    return profile
pl=[]
while True:
    first_name=input("first name: ")
    last_name=input("last name: ")
    no_of_qual=int(input("How many qualification you want to add?"))
    dict_qual={}
    for qual in range(no_of_qual):
        dict_qual[input("Enter subject")]=input("Enter qualification")
    inv_qual = {v: k for k, v in dict_qual.items()}
    pl.append(build_profile(first_name,last_name,inv_qual))
    if input("Want to add more users?(Y/N) ").upper()=="N":
        break
print(pl)
```

Comment: I don't understand, can you provide the desired behavior output? It doesn't make sense to try and override the function call...

Comment: @UriyaHarpeness I was trying to build a user-profile dictionary. While first_name and last_name were common keys for all users but qualifications may vary in level i cannot ask for "Subject" in 'graduation' to every user. May be the user is in high school or user has completed PHD. One way to do this introduce a filed 'level'. But I was trying it the other way. I wanted qualification:subject pair fully entered by user and got stuck while trying to pass a string a function argument. But i have realised my mistake now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use a string as an argument *name* which is not possible. It would probably be better to input an actual dictionary than use an ** argument:

```py
def build_profile(f_name: str, l_name: str, qualification: dict) -> dict:
    return {'first': f_name, 'last': l_name, **qualification}

pl=[]

while True:
    pl.append(build_profile(input("Enter first name: "), \
                            input("Enter last name: "), \
                            {input("Enter value: "):input("Enter subject: ")}))
    if input("Want to finish? (Y/N) ").upper() == "Y":
        break

print(pl)
```

It asks for a value, then a subject (only once).

Comment: Thanks| Actually I understood the problem, Instead of call by value/call by reference/call by object etc. for the function I was simply passing a string and was thinking that it will work. But I know why the error was there.

Answer (score 1):

what you probably want is not to have different keys for different people, but to add one key, for instance "level", for which you can use the different values you ask for (like PHD). So then it looks like this:

```
def build_profile(f_name,l_name,**qualification):
    profile={}
    profile['first']=f_name
    profile['last']=l_name
    for k,v in qualification.items():
        profile[k]=v
    return profile
pl=[]
while True:
    pl.append(build_profile(input("Enter first name: "),\
    input("Enter last name:"),graduation=input("Enter Subject:"),\
    masters=input("Enter Subject:"),\
    level=input("Enter the level"))
    if input("Want to finish?(Y/N) ").upper()=="Y":
        break
print(pl)
```